# Is it possible to use Neo4j database in an Android application?

Tags: android, neo4j, database, nosql

Will it make any error if I use Neo4j database for my Android Application? If so, can anyone suggest me any other Graph database to use as back end for Android application..

Comment: Do you want to access the database via network, or do you want the database to be a part of your app?

Comment: You should be able to use the Neo4j JDBC driver from Android so that you can send Cypher queries to the Neo4j server. See: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc#minimum-viable-snippet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.
While [Neo4J offers a REST API to query the database with the Cypher language](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html), I would recommend to build your own layer on top of that to deal with the requests from Android and then filter and forward to Neo4J.

This layer will let you to use your own business logic between the Android app and the server, logic that will be "translated" in the Cypher syntax later.

If you want to expose instead your DB to the world directly, you can start a Neo4J server on a server (perhaps in read-only mode?) and maybe [enable the HTTPS mode and some more security stuff](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/security-server.html#_https_support).
There are already some [Neo4JaaS](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/cloud) providers out there, so probably you can have a look to that.