# How to update neo4j database in real time from android?

Tags: android, neo4j, real-time, updates

I have used neo4j database for my website. Now I am porting that site on android. I want to implement chat in android app. To save and retrieve the chats I need to save those chats in my database. How to save the chats in neo4j database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167961/is-it-possible-to-use-neo4j-database-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [cypher-transactional-endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) from your android app, either directly or via a driver, like the JDBC driver.

See also our Java language guides: http://neo4j.com/developer/java